# set class of div dynamically attending to div position inside its parent

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have something like this

```
<div id="parentdiv">
     <div class="childiv"></div>
     <div class="childiv"></div>
     <div class="childiv"></div>
     <div class="childiv"></div>
     <div class="childiv"></div>
     <div class="childiv"></div>
</div>
```

I want to dynamically add a class to the 3rd & 6th childdiv and another class to the 1,2,4,5th divs. any ideas?

Comment: Use :nth-child in jQuery to add class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking at every 3rd element you could do:

```
$('.childiv:nth-child(3n+0)')
        .addClass('something')
        .siblings(":not(:nth-child(3n+0))")
        .addClass('somethingElse');
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.addClass()` function can take a callback function, which is passed the index of the element and returns the class to be added.

```
$('#parentdiv').children().addClass(function(i) {
    return ((i % 3) == 2) ? 'class1' : 'class2';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**[fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vz3Tt/)**

### html

```
<div id="parentdiv">
     <div class="childiv">1</div>
     <div class="childiv">2</div>
     <div class="childiv">3</div>
     <div class="childiv">4</div>
     <div class="childiv">5</div>
     <div class="childiv">6</div>
</div>
```

### JQuery

```
$("#parentdiv").find(".childiv:nth-of-type(3n)").addClass('class1');
$("#parentdiv").find(":not(.childiv:nth-of-type(3n))").addClass('class2');
```

### CSS

```
.childiv
{
    font-weight:bold;
}
.class1
{
    color:red;
}
.class2
{
    color:blue;
}
```